# Problems with Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: windows

I have two problems with Windows Task Manager:
One, I have a Python script that sends an email notification, through gmail, at the end of the run. This works fine when I run the script itself, but when I run the script through Windows Task Scheduler, the script runs fine, but does not send an email. Why would this happen?
Two, when running the same script through task scheduler on a remote desktop, when I am logged in, but my session is closed, firefox will not open.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The Task manager doesn't display any GUI for the current user.

You need to be login as system.

Answer (score 0):

A similar thing happened with me ( while using PHP ) and I found out the reason that I had put a relative path to a file to be included in the code.

```
include("./lib/libfile.php");
```

Later when I replaced it with the absolute path it worked all right.

```
include("D://code/lib/libfile.php");
```

You might have a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you need to specify where it starts in. This is important if you make local references in your program.  This would also result in your program running fine, but not doing everything it is built to do.

Inside task scheduler, see "Actions", then edit an action. It's the parameter it says is optional.